# C++ XML Parser (speed, accessing DOM tree)

Tags: c++, dom, c++11, xml-parsing

Has anybody experience with c++ XML parsers (TinyXML, RapidXML,PugiXML, etc...) and knows which ones have fast DOM tree access? I know the performance test from RapidXML [Test](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/manual.html#namespacerapidxml_1performance_charts). But I am interested in the DOM tree access speed (such as cycling through nodes,finding nodes and so on) of these parser.
Does anybody know which is the fastest for c++? Is it still RapidXML?

Answer (score 1):

Just made 2 small unit tests "RapidXML vs TinyXML" on "simple XML files" ranging from 10-100 KB in size. My test console is fully optimized for performance.

1. Unit test#1 
   Looping 100000 times opening the same XML file and parsed it
   Result : RapidXML/TinyXML = 1.19 - rapid 19% faster.
2. Unit test#2
   Parsed a directory containing 247 different XML files again in the same size range: Result : Here the different was insignificant i.e RapidXML/TinyXML = 1.03.

PC : Windows 7 Pro, Precision Tower 3620

Answer (score 0):

PugiXML is usually a little bit faster than RapidXML. Please look at the benchmark results : http://pugixml.org/benchmark/

As you can see, TinyXML is very slow in that bench. Personally i'm using PugiXML, and i'm working with 100 - 400 KB XML files and it works fine.

Comment: But this benchmark only considers parsing speed, not DOM tree access which I'm interested in: (find nodes, iterative loop over nodes)...

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using RapidXML for a project, and it's blazingly fast. Parsing speed is really good, and iterating over the tree is both very easy and fast. Its interface is really easy to use. As iterating over the tree is really all I'm doing (extracting the tree structure and labels for further processing), maybe my experience with it isn't all that helpful to you. But unless every CPU cycle counts, you should probably decide by which interface you like better (or conduct your own experiments and share your results)